# Collect with a product of patterns

Tags: factorization

In the examples below, I notate `Subscript[S, n]` as `Sn` for brevity.

I'm trying to take expressions like

```
a X0 X1 + b X0 X1 + c X1
```

and produce factorisations into the basis of any product of `X` with a unique set of subscripts. The above expression should become

```
(a + b) X0 X1 + c X1
```

Here, `a`, `b` and `c` can be any form which doesn't match the pattern `Subscript[X, _Integer]`. This seems like a job for [`Collect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html), but using a pattern like `X_` factorises to this form:

```
Collect[
    a X0 X1 + b X0 X1 + c X1, 
    X_
]

>>> (c + (a + b) X0) X1
```

Though the 'advanced uses' in the doc include collecting with respect to a parameter, specifying strictly products doesn't seem to work:

```
Collect[
    a X0 X1 + b X0 X1 + c X1, 
    X_ X_
]

>>> a X0 X1 + b X0 X1 + c X1
```

More explicit patterns also don't seem to work:

```
Collect[%, Verbatim[Times][Repeated[X_, {2, Infinity}]]]
>>> a X0 X1 + b X0 X1 + c X1

Collect[%, Verbatim[Times][Except[X_].., Repeated[X_, {2, Infinity}]]]
>>> a X0 X1 + b X0 X1 + c X1
```

I'm looking for a solution which would produce the following transformations, for example

```
a X0 + b X0 -> (a + b) X0
a X0 + b X0 + c X0 X1 + d X0 X1 -> (a + b) X0 + (c + d) X0 X1
```

and similarly for products of a greater number of terms, e.g.

```
a X0 X1 X2 + b X0 X1 X2 + c X1 X2 -> (a + b) X0 X1 X2 + c X1 X2
```

## Adapting Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ's solution:

We can group our input expression ourselves into sums of terms with the same set of subscript indices, pass each to `Factor[]`, then combine.

First, creating a function which returns the subscript indices of the terms that may appear in our input expression:

```
getIndices[ Subscript[X, q_] ] := {q}
getIndices[ Verbatim[Times][ Except[Subscript[X,_]] ..., p:Subscript[X,_].. ] ] := {p}[[ All, 2 ]]
getIndices[ _ ] := {}
```

Note we've here assumed that the `Xn` terms appear *last* in the given products, which is right in most cases, since Mathematica seems to move subscripted symbols to the end of products. If we wanted to be very thorough (to support terms with other subscripted symbols which we want to treat as coefficients yet appear else in the products), we would make our second rule accept any product and extract the `Xn` terms:

```
getIndices[ Verbatim[Times][t__] ] := Cases[{t}, Subscript[X,_]] [[All,2]]
```

`getIndices` merely replaces Αλέξανδρος's use of `Count[]`:

```
myFactor[a_] := Factor /@ GatherBy[List @@@ a, getIndices] // Total
```

This works great, though requires we be explicit about the forms of the terms in our input sums (which we can get by using `Expand` or `Distribute`).

Comment: “ In the examples below, I notate Subscript[S, n] as Sn for brevity.” - please don’t do that. You should just copy / paste your code as it is or we might get down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: I had typed it out verbosely, deemed it very hard to see the format I'm after, and adopted that notation instead. I recognise no one communication style works for everyone, sorry about that!

Comment: Glad to see improvements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code seems to work for the expression structure that has been presented -- Group terms by the number of `X`s and terms with the same number of `X`s are the same, up to a coefficient free of `X`. But no guarantee for expressions with more complex structures.

```
Clear[myFactor]
myFactor[expr_] := Factor /@ Plus @@@ GatherBy[Cases[expr, Times[__]], Count[#, X, -1] &] // Total
```

```
myFactor[a Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + b Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + c Subscript[X, 1]]
myFactor[a Subscript[X, 0] + b Subscript[X, 0]]
myFactor[a Subscript[X, 0] + b Subscript[X, 0] + c Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + d Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1]]
myFactor[a Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2] + b Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2] + c Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2]]
```

> ```
> c Subscript[X, 1] + (a + b) Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1]
> (a + b) Subscript[X, 0]
> (a + b) Subscript[X, 0] + (c + d) Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1]
> c Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2] + (a + b) Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2]
> ```

---

**Update**

To make it more versatile, I wove this piece of code

```
Clear[myFactor2]
myFactor2[expr_] := Keys[#].Values[#] & [
  Total /@ (GroupBy[Cases[expr, Times[a___?(FreeQ[X])] b__ :> {Times[a], Times[b]}], Last -> First] /. x__Times?(Not@*FreeQ[X]) :> 1)
];
```

Besides successful recovery of results from above `myFactor`, as one can check, `myFactor2` can handle more complex cases.

```
myFactor2[a Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2]]
myFactor2[a b Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + b Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + c Subscript[X, 1] + Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2] + Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 0] + c d Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2]]
```

> ```
> a Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2]
> c Subscript[X, 1] + (1 + b + a b) Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] +  Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2] +  c d Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] Subscript[X, 2]
> ```

Comment: Grouping by number-of-X isn't enough; the subscript incides must be unique. E.g. this example `a Subscrip[X,0] Subscript[X, 1] + Subscript[X,1] Subscript[X, 2]` should produce `X0 X1 + X1 X2` but instead produces `X1 (X0 + X2)`

Comment: Replacing your `Count[]` with a function returning the subscript indices does what I want, thanks very much! I'll update my question with the solution

Comment: @AntiEarth At the time I posted the first part of my answer, the situation was that the terms with same number of `X`s had same subscripts, that is why I put "no guarantee blabla". Please see my update.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262530/separating-terms-in-an-expression-with-many-variables-by-their-nature/262532#262532

Answer (score 2):

With an input expression with subscripts, we can use [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) in the second argument to prevent `Subscript[X, _] Subscript[X, _]` from evaluating (to `Power[Subscript[X, Blank[]], 2]`) before pattern matching starts its work:

```
expr = a Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + 
  b Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] + c Subscript[X, 1]
```

[image]

```
Collect[expr, HoldPattern[Subscript[X, _]] Subscript[X, _]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use named patterns (say, `Subscript[X, u_]` instead of `Subscript[X, _]`):

```
Collect[expr, Subscript[X, u_] Subscript[X, v_]]
```

[image]

**Update:** More generally,

```
Collect[expr, Unevaluated[Times[Subscript[X, _] ..]]]
```

[image]

Comment: ahh I indeed missed that `X_ X_` would become `X_^2`, thanks for pointing this out! I'm unsure why `HoldPattern[X_] X_` works yet `HoldPattern[X_ X_]` doesn't, and that's preventing me from generalising to products of more terms

Comment: @AntiEarth, please see the update.

Comment: @kfglr the new code fails for `expr =  a X0 X1 + b X0 X1 X2`, producing `X0 X1 (a + b X2)` instead of leaving the expression unchanged. I couldn't fix it by inserting `Longest[]` inside `Times[]` either

Comment: `Collect[expr, Unevaluated[Times[Subscript[X, _], Subscript[X, _]]]]` leaves `expr` unchanged;  `Collect[expr, Unevaluated[Times[Subscript[X, _] ..]]]` (or `Collect[expr, Unevaluated[Times[Subscript[X, _], Subscript[X, _] ..]]]` gives `Subscript[X, 0] Subscript[X, 1] (a + b Subscript[X, 2])`.

Comment: Exactly.. I'm looking for an expression with the correct behaviour for all inputs

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262530/separating-terms-in-an-expression-with-many-variables-by-their-nature/262532#262532

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you only use subscripts for display, i.e., use formatted indexed variables.

```
Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n];

expr1 = a x[0] x[1] + b x[0] x[1] + c x[1]
```

[image]

```
Collect[expr1, x /@ Range[0, 1]]
```

[image]

```
expr2 = a x[0] x[1] x[2] + b x[0] x[1] x[2] + c x[1] x[2]
```

[image]

```
Collect[expr2, x /@ Range[0, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid subscripted symbols are part of the user input language to the API that my question will ultimately enable. But your gut feeling is correct, and it has indeed proved a nightmare on many occassions ;)